# Symfony2 Sonata Admin Bundle, improve sorting performance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

Ok given:

```
 protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
                ->add('oidval')
                ->add('xxxUserCategory', null, array(
                    'sortable' => true,
                    'sort_field_mapping' => array('fieldName' => 'name'),
                    'sort_parent_association_mappings' => array(array('fieldName' => 'xxxUserCategory')
                    ))
                )
                ->add('xxxUserStatus', null, array(
                    'sortable' => true,
                    'sort_field_mapping' => array('fieldName' => 'name'),
                    'sort_parent_association_mappings' => array(array('fieldName' => 'xxxUserStatus')
                    ))
                )
                ->add('mailboxSize')
                ->add('copyStatus', null, array(
                    'sortable' => true,
                    'sort_field_mapping' => array('fieldName' => 'name'),
                    'sort_parent_association_mappings' => array(array('fieldName' => 'copyStatus')
                    ))
                )
                ->add('copyErrorCount', null, array('label' => 'Copy Error'))
                ->add('currentSiteList.name')
        ;
    }
```

With indexes on each field that is sortable, the resulted query will be:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT i0_.id AS id_0, 
  c1_.name AS name_1 
FROM 
  xxxuser i0_ 
  LEFT JOIN site_list s2_ ON i0_.current_site_list_id = s2_.id 
  LEFT JOIN xxxuser_category i3_ ON i0_.xxxuser_category_id = i3_.id 
  LEFT JOIN xxxuser_status i4_ ON i0_.xxxuser_status_id = i4_.id 
  LEFT JOIN copy_status c1_ ON i0_.copy_status_id = c1_.id 
ORDER BY 
  c1_.name ASC 
LIMIT 
  33 OFFSET 0
```

Which when explained gives:

```
id selected_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE i0_ ALL (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) 1.000.000 Using temporary; using filesort;
2 SIMPLE c1_ eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 xxx.i0_.copy_status_id 1
```

What options do I have in order for me to make my own custom sort query or improve the existing sonata strategy for sorting?
Given the using temporary; using filesort, for 1000000 rows, I get 30 seconds on each sort, which is not feasible.